# Normalise black and white in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

I have some images like this one:
[image: Top-bottom darker]

As you can see, the top and the bottom of the image are darker.
I'd like to normalise the black and white contrast for all the image, in other words, I don't want the top and bottom to be darker, but just as the other part of the image.

Could you please suggest a way to change this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Q</kbd> to activate the **Quick Mask Mode** to make two partial selections

  - Use the **Gradient Tool** from black to transparent and mask the top and bottom areas, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to make the gradient at 90º
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> Win to invert the mask
- Press <kbd>Q</kbd> to exit the **Quick Mask Mode**
- Open the **Levels Panel** and increase the lightness moving the midtones slider to the left

[image: animation]

Answer (score 1):

This could be fixed using the Dodge Tool. Select the Dodge tool, and in the tool options along the top set the Range to "Midtones". Select a large fuzzy brush - larger than the size of the curve of the toe of the shoe print.  A few clicks of the tool on each of the darker areas should be enough to fix it.

[image]